# Is it possible to have WAMP run httpd.exe as user [myself] instead of local SYSTEM?

Tags: apache, wamp

I run a django application over apache with `mod_wsgi`, using WAMP.

A certain URL allows me to stream the content of image files, the paths of which are stored in database.

The files can be located whether on local machine or under network drive (`\\my\network\folder`).

With the development server (manage.py runserver), I have no trouble at all reading and streaming the files.

With WAMP, and with network drive files, I get a `IOError` : obviously because the httpd instance does not have read permission on said drive.

In the task manager, I see that **httpd.exe** is run by **SYSTEM**. I would like to tell WAMP to run the server as [myself] as I have read and write permissions on the shared folder. (eventually, the production server should be run by a 'www-admin' user having the permissions)

Mapping the network shared folder on a drive letter (Z: for instance) does not solve this at all.

The User/Group directives in `httpd.conf` do not seem to have any kind of influence on Apache's behaviour.

I've also regedited : I tried to duplicate the `HKLM\[...]\wampapache` registry key under `HK_CURRENT_USER\` and rename the original key, but then the new key does not seem to be found when I cmd this

```
> httpd.exe -n wampapache -k start
```

or when I run WAMP.

I've run out of ideas :)

Has anybody ever had the same issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Win+R, services.msc

edit wampapache and wampmysqld to log on as some user.

the tray icon is a convenient front end to "net start wampapache" and "net start wampmysqld"

Comment: Perfect, that works. Indeed the tray icon is just a convenient shortcut, but i'm glad I can use it again.

Comment: In my experience, you have to explicitly tell it what user to use, not "Local System Account" http://i.imgur.com/gHKCM6L.png I think "Local System Account" will be admin since the control panel is started as admin. Just for anyone else that stumbles on this.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I had a similar issue where commands would work through the command line, but not when exec with PHP, it was due to the wamp services being started with incorrect permissions.

Comment: In my case names of services are: wampapache64, wampmariadb64 and wampmysqld64. Works like charm after restarting all of the services!

Answer (score 1):

> The User/Group directives in httpd.conf do not seem to have any kind of influence on Apache's behaviour.

httpd.exe is started by the root user (this is probably why you see it running under SYSTEM).  The `user` and `group` lines in httpd.conf determine what user the child processes (that httpd spawns) will run under. These forks are what actually handle page requests, etc. so it is possible that your configuration is already doing what you want it to, it is just unclear from looking at task manager.

You could also try using [`runas`](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/AdminTips/Miscellaneous/RunprogramsasanotheruserinWindows2000WindowsXP.html) to start WAMP/Apache, though your mileage may vary.

Comment: OK, then maybe it's a syntax thing? My login is a windows domain login, any idea on how to formulate this in httpd.conf?

Comment: I've never tried it on Windows, but there are some instructions at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html#winsvc.  I think the part you're probably interested in starts with "By default, all Apache services are registered to run as the system"

Answer (score 1):

I've just found that executing httpd.exe myself works for me... I just loose all the funky WAMP tray icon, and the "restart apache" menu item, really handy whenever I update my application code...

I'll have to make do with this for the moment...