# fopen() permission denied error on shared network folder

Tags: php, wamp, file-permissions, fopen

I recently moved to a new dev PC from my old machine. Both were running my app using a WAMP installation. I am administrator for both. My app needs to read and write to a shared network folder. For some reason I am getting a permission denied error on the **new machine only**.

```
Warning (2): fopen(\\Win7Pro\TSXWork\test.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The shared network drive gives **full control** for '*Anonymous*' and '*Everyone*'. I can view it on the network, add and remove files etc using explorer, but fopen() in my CakePHP app will not work. With my security settings so loose on the shared folder, why would my new PC not have permission?

Comment: Try moving the file into the same directory as your script and let me know if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Cake will be running under the webserver's permissions. Even if the share itself has everyone:read, you still need to grant the IIS user account access rights to the underlying directories that are being shared.

Comment: I am using WAMP, not IIS. Do I still need to grant rights? If so, to which users? There are no explicit rights granted to the admin of my old PC either.

Comment: Yes, whatever user account your webserver is running under needs to have rights on both the share itself AND the underlying filesystem.

Comment: If I can modify files manually in windows explorer, then shouldnt my webserver be able to?

Comment: So I just made Apache run as same username as my old machine rather than waste more time messing around to get it working with new user account.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683766/is-it-possible-to-have-wamp-run-httpd-exe-as-user-myself-instead-of-local-syste]

Comment: In other words, whatever account Apache WAS running under didn't have the proper permissions...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WAMP and nothing worked, for me the problem was solved using XAMPP.