# Can't find SQLite database on network in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I am running my PHP file locally on a WAMP server. Right now it works if the SQLite .db file is on the WAMP server, but as soon as I reference a .db file that isn't on the WAMP server then it can't find it. I have looked everywhere and can't find a similar issue. Here is where I create the .db file:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
        $this->open('J:/scoreboard/SQLite/production_scoreboard.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();
```

I get a PHP error for the line that is opening the .db file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the assigned letter in Windows is probably causing your problem.  `J:` is mapped for you, but not necessarily the user that the web server is running as. It is generally advised to use this format:

```
$this->open('//servername/sharename/scoreboard/SQLite/production_scoreboard.db');
```

Of course, you still might have access issues if the web server user doesn't have rights to that share and file.

If you have permission problems, check the answers here: [Is it possible to have WAMP run httpd.exe as user [myself] instead of local SYSTEM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683766/is-it-possible-to-have-wamp-run-httpd-exe-as-user-myself-instead-of-local-syst)

Apparently wamp server defaults to running as SYSTEM which is definitely NOT going to be able to access network shares.

Comment: I've tried doing that as well. Even when I have it like
`$this->open('//company.ewqg.com/share/scoreboard/SQLite/production_scoreboard.db');` it still doesn't work

Comment: @dge888 appended my answer to contain service user info

Comment: Look at the changes I've made to my answer. :p

Comment: Ugh still nothing. I found where to log in as a user, then I restarted all of the services, but still no luck.

Comment: If the web service is now running as you, you can test by opening a cmd window and try to `cd` to the same dir you're specifying, like `cd //servername/sharename/scoreboard/SQLite/`

Comment: BAM! Got it! so going into the filesystem in Cygwin I was able to see that there was an additional directory between 'share' and 'scoreboard'. Once I added that in, it worked great. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nothing better than solving that annoying little detail. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error? It can be a couple of thinks. 
Are the permissions and owners of the folder / file correctly?

Are you in the scope of the Script?

You see, we need the PHP error... ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. Here are the errors `( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file' in C:\wamp\www\websites\includes\php\getTable.php on line 18  

( ! ) Exception: Unable to open database: unable to open database file in C:\wamp\www\websites\includes\php\getTable.php on line 18`

Comment: Sorry if that is hard to read. Can't figure out how to format it. My permissions for the folder are set correctly, I even tried doing a `chmod 777` on everything in it just to make sure

Comment: i think the file permissions and owners are incorrect. because if the file or directory not present you will get an "such file or directory error"