# PHP exec output differs from Command line output?

Tags: php, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Context:** 
I have a simple html frontend that allows the user to enter some basic detail, e.g. colours to use. This then gets placed in my strings.xml file so that we can quickly push out preview versions. Windows 10 64bit running WAMP, building with Gradle 3.6.

**The Goal:**
To build the updated app from command line with PHP.

**The issue:**
The project builds correctly when I manually build via the command line, but the build fails when I use PHP's exec function.

The gradle wrapper has to be executed from the base project folder, thus the need for `cd`...

Firstly I clean the project, so I do:`cd path/to/projectdir && gradlew clean 2>&1`
Which work as expected from exec and command line.

Next is to build with `cd path/to/projectdir && gradlew assemble 2>&1`.
Running the above via command line returns success:

[image: command line build success]

However, running the same with `exec('cd path/to/projectdir && gradlew assemble 2>&1', $output)` and printing output returns: 
...`[24] => FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [25] => 
    [26] => * What went wrong:
    [27] => Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.`... (full output https://pastebin.com/zdeXuukp)

As far as I can tell, the only difference between the two, is the process owner (based on exec('whoami')).
Any idea if this might be the cause for it failing or what else might be causing the PHP exec build to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, my suspicions were confirmed, it was indeed due to the apache user having incorrect permissions. 
This is the answer: [Is it possible to have WAMP run httpd.exe as user [myself] instead of local SYSTEM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683766/is-it-possible-to-have-wamp-run-httpd-exe-as-user-myself-instead-of-local-syst)

In this instance, I was just playing around on my local machine and would obviously not recommend this approach in a production environment, anyway, here's how I solved it:

1. Close WAMP.
2. Open services.msc (win+r services.msc)
3. Change wampapache64, wampmariadb64 & wampmysqld64 Right click>Properties > Logon Tab and specify a User account to start the service as (I used my user account, as I knew it already has the correct permissions) and Apply changes.
4. Open WAMP.
5. Accessing a PHP page through the browser with a simple `echo exec('whoami')` should now output the same as running `whoami` directly in the command line.

My script is now executing correctly and returning the same output as when run through the command line.